# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in ajax request, but not by clicking on a <a> tag link

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cors, hapi.js

I am using `HapiJS` and Bell to authenticate users. I have an endPoint that is responsible to authenticate the users.

```
  server.route({
    method: ['POST','GET'],
    path: '/token',
    config: {
      auth: 'twitter',
      handler: function (request, reply) {

       reply(request.auth.credentials.profile)

      }
    }
  });
```

When I have an `<a>` tag link pointing to that endPoint everything works well, I am redirecting to twitter to authenticate and then I see the `reply`. What I want is to make that through `ajax` request so I can handle the response using `then`.

So I have something simple:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8001/token'
}).then(function(data){
  console.log('>>>>>>>>>',data);
});
```

I click a button and I make the request, but in this case I have the following message on Chrome `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=TPSmxB22abgI2jC8DvEgUxKOc4ZadsSI. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` Any idea how can I solve that?

Comment: You can't do this because your server is redirecting the request to Twitter's API which is then redirecting back to a different endpoint of your server. You can't do this over XHR because if the user isn't logged into Twitter then Twitter will prompt them to enter their credentials before finally redirecting back to your server and that's something that simply cannot be done via XHR.

Answer (score 1):

Because your session is from the HapiJS/Bell authentication process, making a GET to localhost is giving you CORS Header issues. You need to attach the headers serverside, wherever you spin your Node server up.

Comment: can you provide an example? I cant find something related on the docs.

Answer (score -1):

```
res.header("access-control-allow-origin","client domain including protocol")
```

Comment: Please add more details and explain your answer.